# Writing Flash SOL files with C/C++/Python/Perl

Tags: flash, amf

I was using PyAMF to write Adobe Flash SOL files. PyAMF is dead, and is not maintained any more. It has compilation issues so there is no way to use it on the modern system. Does anyone know a good way how to write a SOL file with C/C++/Python/Perl?

Comment: Why do you say that PyAMF is dead?  I see commits up on https://github.com/hydralabs/pyamf as late as Oct. 14 of this year.  And what compilation issues are you having?  I was able to build it earlier today without issues.

Comment: "Why do you say that PyAMF is dead?" - 

It has been removed from Ubuntu/Jessie/Sid repositories due to compilation errors. Looks like there is no maintainer to fix that. When I tried to recompile the deb package by myself I've got the following errors: http://pastebin.com/t3q90KRe

Answer (score 0):

The root of the build breakages are that current builds of PyAMF don't support modern versions of cython.  Without cython (e.g., if you uninstall it or build it in a clean virtualenv), you should be able to build from source using its pure python codecs.

There's a better solution on the horizon though.  Over the last several months, others have been working on pyamf, and there is an [open and active pull request](https://github.com/hydralabs/pyamf/pull/30) that should resolve the build issues and fix other bugs.

If you're OK building outside of pristine distro sources, I would recommend using a branch from the above pull request or otherwise building from pure sources without the cython extension.